# Count number of occurences of a column changing value from 0 to 1 and 0 to 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

Suppose I have `df1['col1']` and `df2['col2']` both columns equal in length.
The values in the columns are `0`, `1` and `2` only.

How do I find the counts of changes from `0` -> `2` and `1` -> `2` from `df1` to `df2` if each corresponding row in the `df` is a transition about an element?

As an example, I need to count the changes in the 2 columns below

```
    print(df1['orig_label'][0:5])
    Name: predicted_label, dtype: int64
    0    2
    1    2
    2    0
    3    0
    4    1

print(df2['predicted_label'][0:5])
Name: predicted_label, dtype: int64
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
```

Expected output: 1 and 1

which are counts of 0->2 and 1->2 transition

Comment: Will you please provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: I just need to print the counts, no need of saving in a new df

Comment: Then will you please generate a sample dataframe (maybe with `df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, (20,2)))`), and then add sample printed output? As it is, the question is hard for me to visualize.

Comment: Please check my updates above

Comment: Sorry, by "printed output" I meant "the print output" that you're trying to get...

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for `pandas.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df1['col1'], df2['col2'])
```

Output:

```
col2  0  1  2
col1         
0     1  0  1
1     0  0  1
2     0  2  0
```

To get only 0->2 and 1->2:

```
pd.crosstab(df1['col1'], df2['col2']).loc[[0,1], [2]]
```

Output:

```
col2  2
col1   
0     1
1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":[0,1,2,3,4], "col2":[2,2,0,0,1]}, columns=["col1", "col2"])

df["0->2"] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row["col1"] == 0 and row["col2"] == 2 else 0, axis=1)
df["1->2"] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row["col1"] == 1 and row["col2"] == 2 else 0, axis=1)

print("N 0->2 = {}".format(df["0->2"].sum()))
print("N 1->2 = {}".format(df["1->2"].sum()))
```

This has the potential downside of adding two additional columns to your original dataframe, but you could also just create them as separate series objects if you don't want to do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":[0,1,2,3,4], "col2":[2,2,0,0,1]}, columns=["col1", "col2"])
zeroToTwo = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row["col1"] == 0 and row["col2"] == 2 else 0, axis=1)
oneToTwo = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row["col1"] == 1 and row["col2"] == 2 else 0, axis=1)
print("N 0->2 = {}".format(zeroToTwo.sum()))
print("N 1->2 = {}".format(oneToTwo.sum()))
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `apply` (very slow) but rather vectorial operations. Such as `(df1['col1'].eq(0) & df2['col2'].eq(2))` and `numpy.where`

Comment: @mozway - Agreed.  A built-in vectorized function is definitely better way to go.  Wasn't aware of pandas.crosstab() function.  Thanks for pointing that method out in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `zip()` and `value_counts()`

```
(pd.Series(['0-2' if (col1 == 0 and col12 == 2) else '1-2' if (col1 == 1 and col2 == 2) else None for col1,col2 in zip(df['col1'],df['col2'])])
 .value_counts())
```

Output

```
0-2    1
1-2    1
dtype: int64
```